# Bipartite graphs not hamiltonian-connected

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, bipartite-graphs

How can I prove that no bipartite graph is hamiltonian-connected?

I thought I could use another problem of my homework:
Ks,t is hamiltonian iff s=t
But I don't really see how

Or Should I try induction?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2059091

Answer (score 1):

You have all you need right now.

A graph is Hamilton-connected if any two vertices can be joined by a Hamilton path. So all you need to do is show that if two vertices from different parts of a bipartition can be joined by a Hamilton path, then two vertices from the same part cannot.

(With the exception of $K_{1,1}$, which is Hamilton-connected.)